# Fixing the No overload for method problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am keep having the "No overload for method 'GenerateSignature' takes 9 arguments" problem. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this class.
This code is the sample from the Oauth.net . I think it too old for my asp.net 3.5 or 4.0.

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="OAuth" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%
OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();
Uri url = new Uri("http://ssdsdafdasfdsafdsa.example.net/photos?file=vacation.jpg&size=original");
string signature = oauth.GenerateSignature(url,"dpf43f3p2l4k3l03", "kd94hf93k423kf44", "nnch734d00sl2jdk", "pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00", "GET", oauth.GenerateTimeStamp(), oauth.GenerateNonce(), OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1);
         %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The app_code
//THE APP_CODE

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace OAuth {
    public class OAuthBase {
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides a predefined set of algorithms that are supported officially by the protocol
        /// </summary>
        public enum SignatureTypes {
            HMACSHA1,
            PLAINTEXT,
            RSASHA1
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides an internal structure to sort the query parameter
        /// </summary>
        protected class QueryParameter {
            private string name = null;
            private string value = null;

            public QueryParameter(string name, string value) {
                this.name = name;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public string Name {
                get { return name; }
            }

            public string Value {
                get { return value; }
            }            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Comparer class used to perform the sorting of the query parameters
        /// </summary>
        protected class QueryParameterComparer : IComparer<QueryParameter> {

            #region IComparer<QueryParameter> Members

            public int Compare(QueryParameter x, QueryParameter y) {
                if (x.Name == y.Name) {
                    return string.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
                } else {
                    return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }

        protected const string OAuthVersion = "1.0";
        protected const string OAuthParameterPrefix = "oauth_";

        //
        // List of know and used oauth parameters' names
        //        
        protected const string OAuthConsumerKeyKey = "oauth_consumer_key";
        protected const string OAuthCallbackKey = "oauth_callback";
        protected const string OAuthVersionKey = "oauth_version";
        protected const string OAuthSignatureMethodKey = "oauth_signature_method";
        protected const string OAuthSignatureKey = "oauth_signature";
        protected const string OAuthTimestampKey = "oauth_timestamp";
        protected const string OAuthNonceKey = "oauth_nonce";
        protected const string OAuthTokenKey = "oauth_token";
        protected const string OAuthTokenSecretKey = "oauth_token_secret";

        protected const string HMACSHA1SignatureType = "HMAC-SHA1";
        protected const string PlainTextSignatureType = "PLAINTEXT";
        protected const string RSASHA1SignatureType = "RSA-SHA1";

        protected Random random = new Random();

        protected string unreservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper function to compute a hash value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hashAlgorithm">The hashing algoirhtm used. If that algorithm needs some initialization, like HMAC and its derivatives, they should be initialized prior to passing it to this function</param>
        /// <param name="data">The data to hash</param>
        /// <returns>a Base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        private string ComputeHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, string data) {
            if (hashAlgorithm == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("hashAlgorithm");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataBuffer);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Internal function to cut out all non oauth query string parameters (all parameters not begining with "oauth_")
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameters">The query string part of the Url</param>
        /// <returns>A list of QueryParameter each containing the parameter name and value</returns>
        private List<QueryParameter> GetQueryParameters(string parameters) {
            if (parameters.StartsWith("?")) {
                parameters = parameters.Remove(0, 1);
            }

            List<QueryParameter> result = new List<QueryParameter>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)) {
                string[] p = parameters.Split('&');
                foreach (string s in p) {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && !s.StartsWith(OAuthParameterPrefix)) {
                        if (s.IndexOf('=') > -1) {
                            string[] temp = s.Split('=');
                            result.Add(new QueryParameter(temp[0], temp[1]));
                        } else {
                            result.Add(new QueryParameter(s, string.Empty));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a different Url Encode implementation since the default .NET one outputs the percent encoding in lower case.
        /// While this is not a problem with the percent encoding spec, it is used in upper case throughout OAuth
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to Url encode</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a Url encoded string</returns>
        protected string UrlEncode(string value) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char symbol in value) {
                if (unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) != -1) {
                    result.Append(symbol);
                } else {
                    result.Append('%' + String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Normalizes the request parameters according to the spec
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameters">The list of parameters already sorted</param>
        /// <returns>a string representing the normalized parameters</returns>
        protected string NormalizeRequestParameters(IList<QueryParameter> parameters) {         
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            QueryParameter p = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++) {
                p = parameters[i];
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", p.Name, p.Value);

                if (i < parameters.Count - 1) {
                    sb.Append("&");
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate the signature base that is used to produce the signature
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
        /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>        
        /// <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
        /// <param name="signatureType">The signature type. To use the default values use <see cref="OAuthBase.SignatureTypes">OAuthBase.SignatureTypes</see>.</param>
        /// <returns>The signature base</returns>
        public string GenerateSignatureBase(Uri url, string consumerKey, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, string signatureType, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters) {
            if (token == null) {
                token = string.Empty;
            }

            if (tokenSecret == null) {
                tokenSecret = string.Empty;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerKey");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpMethod)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpMethod");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureType)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("signatureType");
            }

            normalizedUrl = null;
            normalizedRequestParameters = null;

            List<QueryParameter> parameters = GetQueryParameters(url.Query);
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthVersionKey, OAuthVersion));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthNonceKey, nonce));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthTimestampKey, timeStamp));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthSignatureMethodKey, signatureType));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthConsumerKeyKey, consumerKey));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) {
                parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthTokenKey, token));
            }

            parameters.Sort(new QueryParameterComparer());

            normalizedUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", url.Scheme, url.Host);
            if (!((url.Scheme == "http" && url.Port == 80) || (url.Scheme == "https" && url.Port == 443)))
            {
                normalizedUrl += ":" + url.Port;
            }
            normalizedUrl += url.AbsolutePath;
            normalizedRequestParameters = NormalizeRequestParameters(parameters);

            StringBuilder signatureBase = new StringBuilder();          
            signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}&", httpMethod.ToUpper());
            signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}&", UrlEncode(normalizedUrl));
            signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}", UrlEncode(normalizedRequestParameters));

            return signatureBase.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate the signature value based on the given signature base and hash algorithm
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="signatureBase">The signature based as produced by the GenerateSignatureBase method or by any other means</param>
        /// <param name="hash">The hash algorithm used to perform the hashing. If the hashing algorithm requires initialization or a key it should be set prior to calling this method</param>
        /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        public string GenerateSignatureUsingHash(string signatureBase, HashAlgorithm hash) {
            return ComputeHash(hash, signatureBase);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a signature using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm
        /// </summary>      
        /// <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
        /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>
        /// <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer seceret</param>
        /// <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
        /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters) {            
            return GenerateSignature(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a signature using the specified signatureType 
        /// </summary>      
        /// <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
        /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>
        /// <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer seceret</param>
        /// <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
        /// <param name="signatureType">The type of signature to use</param>
        /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, SignatureTypes signatureType, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters) {
            normalizedUrl = null;
            normalizedRequestParameters = null;

            switch (signatureType) {
                case SignatureTypes.PLAINTEXT:                  
                    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecret, tokenSecret));
                case SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1:                   
                    string signatureBase = GenerateSignatureBase(url, consumerKey, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, HMACSHA1SignatureType, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);

                    HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();
                    hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", UrlEncode(consumerSecret), string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenSecret) ? "" : UrlEncode(tokenSecret)));

                    return GenerateSignatureUsingHash(signatureBase, hmacsha1);                                        
                case SignatureTypes.RSASHA1:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown signature type", "signatureType");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate the timestamp for the signature        
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual string GenerateTimeStamp() {
            // Default implementation of UNIX time of the current UTC time
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a nonce
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual string GenerateNonce() {
            // Just a simple implementation of a random number between 123400 and 9999999
            return random.Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I only see 2 overloads, 1 with 10 args and 1 with 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two overloads for GenerateSignature. One has 10 parameters:

```
public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, 
    string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, 
    string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce,
    SignatureTypes signatureType, out string normalizedUrl,
    out string normalizedRequestParameters)
```

And one has 11:

```
public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey,
    string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, 
    string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, 
    SignatureTypes signatureType, out string normalizedUrl,
    out string normalizedRequestParameters)
```

Now there are two options here. The "get it working quickly" option is just to make your code actually call one of the existing signatures. In this case, I believe you just need the two `out` parameters at the end - but you don't need the `SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1` argument, as the overload with 10 parameters uses that anyway.

However, the *better* option is to change the design of your class. 11 parameters, two of them being `out` parameters, is a pretty horrible signature to work with.

Encapsulate the incoming parameters in one class - possibly just one with a bunch of automatically implemented properties - and encapsulate the return values (the two out parameters and the existing string return value) in another class. That will make it much easier to work with. In fact, you may want to split the incoming parameters into sections, rather than just one class with 9 properties. If some of the properties change between requests but some are always the same, that *may* be a useful point at which to split the class up.

Comment: thank you very much for the recommendation. I have converted one of the public string GenerateSignature. Thank you.  I don't need the full function so i went ahead and converted into 1 public string and it is working now.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the out parameters for the GenerateSignature call.